# How to rotate an Instruction on a kivy Canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I would like to know how to rotate an Instruction (a Rectangle for example) on a kivy canvas, without rotating the whole canvas and without rotating any other instructions, without using the kv language if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Rotate canvas instruction, in combination with PushMatrix and PopMatrix to constrain the affected area, e.g. in kv language:

```
canvas:
    PushMatrix:
    Rotate:
        angle: 0.3
    PopMatrix:
```

or the equivalent in a `with canvas:` block in python code.

Comment: I do however notice some flickering now (I am calling this change every 0.1 seconds). Is there anyway to stop the flickering, or should i not call this change this often?

Comment: I don't think this should flicker, maybe raise an issue on the kivy mailing list (or even a github issue) with a runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the thread that calls the function that creates and rotates the instruction is separated from the main thread, and the flickering only occurs when I drag the canvas the instructions are in (the widget that contains the canvas is inside a scrollView).

Comment: I'm not sure that those things should matter, but I don't know. It would need a minimal runnable example, and maybe a comparison between threaded and unthreaded, to check.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have managed to get it to work by replacing the thread I was using by a chain of Clock.schedule_once() commands. For some reason that stopped the flickering so I guess it must have been something to do with me not threading properly.